# Spring security "Remember Me" Checkbox

Tags: java, spring, cookies, authentication, spring-security

I have a Web Application and my backend uses spring security. I managed to implement the normal login but now I want to extend it so that users don't have to log in each time the sessionid cookie expires. I also do not wish to extend the validity of said cookie. Instead I want to leave this choice up to the users. Who wants to stay logged in can do so and the other users should be logged out automatically after a certain time. I would like to achieve this with the help of a checkbox in the login form. How could this be achieved? I managed to find information about the remember me cookie but to the best of my understanding this has a global effect, making all users remain logged in.

Here is my WebConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
        // ...Long series of .antMatchers...
        .antMatchers("/login", "/getActiveUser", "/logout")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8100", true);
}
```

And my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/projectdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
server.session.cookie.max-age=600
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Add the below configuration to the http object,

```
http.rememberMe().key("mySecretKey").tokenValiditySeconds(86400);
```

and the below to login page,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" />
```

Comment: could you please explain the approach a bit?

Comment: plus I do not want a finite period of time